# add more 1 in quantity if item is already in array

Tags: php

I have an array in session.

```
array(2) { 

[0]=> array(5) { 

["id"]=> string(1) "3" 
["titulo"]=> string(25) "product 1" 
["quantidade"]=> int(1) 
["preco"]=> string(7) "1000.00" 
["image"]=> string(15) "/img/no_img.png" 
} 

[1]=> array(5) { 
["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
["titulo"]=> string(43) "product 2" 
["quantidade"]=> int(1) 
["preco"]=> string(6) "157.20" 
["image"]=> string(14) "produtos/1.jpg" 
}

}
```

for example, if user add the same product again (eg: id 3), I'd like to add +1 in its quantity (quantidade) only.

I tried this, but products are always creating a new array, not updating the quantity.

Any ideas why?

```
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
        if(in_array($produto, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($produto == $k) {
                        if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantidade"])) {
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantidade"] = 1;
                        }
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantidade"] += 1;
                    }
            }
        } 
        else {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
        }
    } 
    else {
        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
    }
```

$produto is the ID I'd like to update.

Comment: What is the array in the `var_dump()` at the start, is that `$_SESSION['cart_item']`? And what is in `$produto`? If that's the product-id of the item you want to add to the cart, surely you need to be looking in the data, not the array keys?

Comment: @RickJoe, the same problem as in your previous question - wrong comparison :) You have to use `if($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]['id'] == $produto)`.

Comment: This would be so much easier if you use the `id` as the array key.

Comment: @mitkosoft strange, I am asking this question to add itens because I tried to change the `if` as the answer in question to remove, but here the array is not changing the quantity, it always adding +1. I think there is something else wrong...

Comment: As @Nikolas mentioned in his answer below, `if(in_array($produto, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))` is also wrong.

Comment: Thanks all friends!

Comment: I would use the product ID (assuming that is a unique value) as the array key in a situation like this - makes it easier to look up whether an entry for a specific product already exists, `isset($dataArray[$productId])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$k` variable contains the current array index [0,1,2,3], not the value of the current array id.

I'd try to compare your `$producto` with `$_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]['id']` instead. I've also changed your condition to strictly compare both values ( `===` ) which is always a good idea.

One more things.
I'm not sure this line is relevent

```
if(in_array($produto, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
```

You are trying to check if `$produto` is in the keys of `$_SESSION["cart_item"]`. However, the keys of `$_SESSION["cart_item"]` are the index that starts at 0. So the id 1 might not be at position 1.

You'd be better of using another variable ( lets say `$dirty`)  to check if your current array was updated.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
         $dirty = false;
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($produto === $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]['id']) {
                        $dirty = true
                        if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantidade"])) {
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantidade"] = 1;
                        }
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantidade"] += 1;
                    }
            }

           if(!$dirty) {
                // the id was not present in the array
                // we need to add it.
                $_SESSION["cart_item"][] = [...];
           }
    } 
    else {
        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
    }
```

Please note that this code is untested.

Comment: It is working to add +1 in quantity, but when I try to add another product, with another id, it is not adding, any ideas?

Comment: @RickJoe it's in the `if(!$dirty)` section. The `$dirty` variable is false only if no product in the current array with the id `$produto` was found. This is when you add your new array.

Comment: Oh, so I should use the `array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);` there? :)

Comment: it is perfect now with `$_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);` in the dirty part. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad i could help !